# Cannot upload image in vue.js laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to upload an image which is in base64 format using below code

```
upload: function(e) { 
      const tmpFiles = e.target.files;
      if (tmpFiles.length === 0) {
            return false;
      }
      const file = tmpFiles[0]; 
      const self = this;
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
      self.form.imageData.push(e.target.result);
     }
}
```

issue is if i access `this.form.imageData` outside onload function then i get null and in my controller also i'm not getting image data, but when i print it using `self.form.imageData` inside onload function then i get image data in base64 encoded format.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to run the ajax call inside the reader's onload method.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)